# VENV folder for a project disappears automatically after some time when i close project

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

Im using pycharm and when i create a new project a venv is created in same project folder.
now when i close that project or create new project and then come back to first project after some time (or few days) that vene is not there any more. and gets error
'No interpreter configured for this project '

I need to again create new venv to get it working.

Is there any way to permantly fix this so that no mater whenever i come back venv should be there in project folder?
please help!
Thanks in advance!

Note: i think i understood what is happening when i create a new project pycharm is using vene of previous project and when i close there is basiacally no project specific vene that's why i come back i done see any venv there

Answer (score 0):

Try to create you venv using pycharm it self.It work for me.

Comment: I am creating venv using pycham itself, by accepting defaults at the beginning of project. still some how its disappears once i open other project and come back to it after some time

Comment: did you try to create it using  `virtualenv` library?

Comment: i think i found the root cause thanks for replying tough